# Calculate the minimum value of a certain column for all the groups and subtract the value from all the values of a certain column of that group

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2018-02-03',42],
                   ['2018-02-03',22],
                   ['2018-02-03',10],
                   ['2018-02-03',32],
                   ['2018-02-03',10],
                   ['2018-02-04',8],
                   ['2018-02-04',2],
                   ['2018-02-04',12],
                   ['2018-02-03',20],
                   ['2018-02-05',30],
                   ['2018-02-05',5],
                   ['2018-02-05',15]])
df.columns = ['product','date','quantity']
```

I want to create groups by date and calculate the minimum value of a 'quantity' column for all the groups respectively and subtract the value from all the values of a 'quantity' column of that group. The desired output is:

```
day         value
2018-02-03  32                #(because, 42-10 = 32), 10 is minimum for date 2018-02-03.
2018-02-03  12
2018-02-03  0
2018-02-03  22
2018-02-03  0
2018-02-04  6
2018-02-04  0
2018-02-04  10
2018-02-03  10
2018-02-05  25
2018-02-05  0
2018-02-05  10
```

Now, this is what I tried:

```
df = df.groupby('Date', as_index = True)
datamin = df.groupby('Date')['quantity'].min()
```

Bu this creates a dataframe with the first quantity by Date ana I also do not know, how to proceed after this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For improve performance use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) without lambda function, better is subtract all values of column like:

```
df['value'] = df['quantity'].sub(df.groupby('date')['quantity'].transform('min'))
```

Answer (score 2):

try via `groupby()` and `transform()`:

```
df['value']=df.groupby('date')['quantity'].transform(lambda x:x-x.min())
```

output of `df`:

```
    date         quantity   value
0   2018-02-03      42      32
1   2018-02-03      22      12
2   2018-02-03      10      0
3   2018-02-03      32      22
4   2018-02-03      10      0
5   2018-02-04      8       6
6   2018-02-04      2       0
7   2018-02-04      12      10
8   2018-02-03      20      10
9   2018-02-05      30      25
10  2018-02-05      5       0
11  2018-02-05      15      10
```